# Knex error using where clause in joins

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am using the following query:

```
const all = (context, merchantId) => {

  return knex(TABLE)
    .join('address', 'address.id', '=', 'hotel.id')
    .select(
        'hotel.id', 'hotel.name', 'hotel.description', 'hotel.thumbnail',
        'address.city', 'address.state', 'address.country')
    .where('merchant_id', merchantId)
    .then(rows => {
      return rows;
    });
};
```

But getting error:

```
Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select `hotel`.`id`, `hotel`.`name`, `hotel`.`description`, `hotel`.`thumbnail`, `address`.`city`, `address`.`state`, `address`.`country` from `hotel` inner join `address` on `address`.`id` = `hotel`.`id` where `merchant_id` = ?
```

What I am missing?

Comment: What will be printed out if you will print `merchantId` directly before `return` ?

Comment: @LEQADA I confirm that was the problem, but error thrown is really misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [knex.js documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-wheres)

> **Important**: Supplying knex with an undefined value to any of the where
> functions will cause knex to throw an error during sql compilation.
> This is both for yours and our sake. Knex cannot know what to do with
> undefined values in a where clause, and generally it would be a
> programmatic error to supply one to begin with. The error will throw a
> message containing the type of query and the compiled query-string.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> knex('accounts')
> .where('login', undefined)
> .select()
> .toSQL()
> ```
>
> Error:
>
> ```
> Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select *
> from `accounts` where `login` = ?
> ```

So I can guess that `merchantId` in your code is undefined